# Does a Checkbox Need User Input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I'm building functionality on top of a Shopify app ("Unlimited Product Options"), of which I do not have access to their JS code and I'm not sure if I need to post my code here to have this question answered, so my apologies if I do.

I have a product option in the form of a checkbox.  When this checkbox is checked, it increases the price, and when unchecked, decreases the price.

I have it set up where, at some point, the checkbox is unchecked using jQuery, without user input:

```
$('#'+carabinerEmber).prop( "checked", false );
```

However, if this code is used AFTER a box has already been checked via user input, it will not reduce the price as it should.  I have checked and made sure that it's actually unchecked logging it's value through the console.

I'm wondering if the fact that it's being changed through JS code and not user input has anything to do with it.  Is this a thing?

Thanks

Comment: after unchecking using JS run the change event for user input manually

Comment: Yes. Changing it by user input fires an event, your way doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Event will not fired automatically, if you are changing the property programmatically.

You can use [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to fire the `change` event.

```
$('#'+carabinerEmber).prop( "checked", false ).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I use this code, although it does change the state of the checkbox, it doesn't adjust the price like it does when clicking with the mouse.  Maybe I'm missing something else?